# Should I choose 5400rpm or 7200rpm hdds for setup RAID 1 on B450 AMD Chipset board

Tags: hard-disk, sata, raid, raid-controller

I have ASUS ROG STRIX B450-F which uses the AMD B450 chipset, I plan on adding 2 SATA drives in a RAID 1 configuration and am trying to determine if there is any advantage to using 7200rpm drives.

I found posts from a few years back that indicated that there was no point in using 7200 rpm drives because the RAID controller was the bottleneck.

Is this still the case? Is anyone able to find any specs on the B450 chipset RAID Controller?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

1. SATA 1  150mb/s
2. SATA 2  300mb/s
3. SATA 3  600mb/s

If the RAID controller has SATA 3 connectors it should be able to handle it.  If you are looking for raw speed a samsung ssd will do 500-550mb/s read and 300+mb/s write beating any 2 hard drives you can attach via SATA.